# Number of full moons between two given dates

Tags: mathematical-astronomy

How does one calculate the number of full moons between two given dates d1 and d2 > d1. The date d3 of a full moon is also given.

Say, what is the number of full moons between:
15-Nov-1936 and 23-Oct-2017
or
21-Sep-1940 and 24-Jul-2021?
Given that 15-Aug-2000 was a full moon day.

Comment: I would do it using a table of full moon occurrences and just count. But taking the number of days in the time interval and dividing by 29.5 will give a pretty good estimate.

Comment: Could we have a routine to do this easily, say as a library function in various computer languages (such as Python, C#, Swift, Go and so on)? Could WolframAlpha help?